# Amazon product details page scraping selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, browser-automation

**I want to scrape the details page from amazon.com. where product price change over products size. I want to itarate over each dropdown size list, but after clicking one size it shows StaleElementReferenceException. Can anyone modify my code to click each size for each color family? ***Love in advance*****

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time

path = Service('../driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=path)
driver.maximize_window()

web = 'https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Essentials-Loose-Fit-Short-Sleeve-Crewneck/dp/B0775CT1J9/ref=sr_1_17?c=ts&keywords=Men%27s+T-Shirts&qid=1688295104&s=apparel&sr=1-17&ts_id=1045624'

try:
    driver.get(web)
    title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span#productTitle'))).text
    print('Title: ', title)
    try:
        color_boxes = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@role="radiogroup"]/li')))
        for color_box in color_boxes:
            color_box.click()
            color_family = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#variation_color_name span.selection'))).text
            print('color_family: ', color_family)
            time.sleep(1)
            size_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#dropdown_selected_size_name')
            size_box.click()
            size_available = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.dropdownAvailable')))
            for size in size_available:
                try:
                    size.click()
                    price = WebDriverWait(driver,6).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.reinventPricePriceToPayMargin span.a-price-whole'))).text
                    print(f'price: {price}')
                except StaleElementReferenceException:
                    print("Stale element reference exception occurred.")
                    pass
                size_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#dropdown_selected_size_name')))
                size_box.click()
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        pass
    print('...........................................................................................')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Product not found")
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Stale Element Reference Exception](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/#stale-element-reference-exception) occurs when you try to use/access element that has already changed when during the code execution.

In your case when you first checked for `size_available`, driver created a reference ID. Then later, when you called `size.click()`, a class `a-active` was added to element `li` pointing that size, resulting a change in element, which the reference ID couldn't find. So, you could no longer use that `size_available`, and the `for loop` using that `size_available` threw stale element error.

One way to solve this is to create new `size_available` on each loop and use length of `size_available` as condition for loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# path = Service('../driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=Options().add_argument('--disable-extensions'))
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.maximize_window()

web = 'https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Essentials-Loose-Fit-Short-Sleeve-Crewneck/dp/B0775CT1J9/ref=sr_1_17?c=ts&keywords=Men%27s+T-Shirts&qid=1688295104&s=apparel&sr=1-17&ts_id=1045624'

driver.get(web)
title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span#productTitle'))).text
print('Title: ', title)
color_boxes = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@role="radiogroup"]/li')))
for color_box in color_boxes:
    color_box.click()
    color_family = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#variation_color_name span.selection'))).text
    print('color_family: ', color_family)
    # used option to get length
    sizes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select[name="dropdown_selected_size_name"] > option')
    size_available_num = len(sizes)
    size_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#dropdown_selected_size_name')))
    # first item in list is Select text so skipped that
    for num in range(1, size_available_num):
        actions.move_to_element(size_box).perform()
        size_box.click()
        # li.dropdownAvailable keeps changing so used li.a-dropdown-item
        size_available = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.a-dropdown-item')))
        size = size_available[num]
        print(f'size: {size.text}')
        size.click()
        # print(f'size: {size.text}')   # size attributes changed when clicked so can't use here
        # used span to get $11.80 instead of just 11 just because.
        price = WebDriverWait(driver,6).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.reinventPricePriceToPayMargin > span'))).get_attribute('innerText')
        print(f'price: {price}')
    # break
    print('...........................................................................................')
```

OUTPUT:

```
size: X-Small
price: $11.18
size: Small
price: $11.18
size: Medium
price: $11.18
size: Large
price: $11.18
size: X-Large
price: $11.18
size: XX-Large
price: $11.18
...........................................................................................
color_family:  Black
size: X-Small
price: $11.18
size: Small
price: $11.18
size: Medium
price: $11.18
size: Large
price: $11.18
size: X-Large
price: $11.18
size: XX-Large
price: $11.18
...........................................................................................
color_family:  Black/Charcoal Heather
size: X-Small
price: $11.18
size: Small
price: $11.18
size: Medium
price: $11.18
size: Large
price: $11.18
size: X-Large
...
...
```

EDIT:

I noticed all price are same. You can add time.sleep() or look for `js-feature-refresh-overlay`. I also added exception when product/price is not available.

```
try:
    price = WebDriverWait(driver,6).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div:not(.js-feature-refresh-overlay) span.a-offscreen'))).get_attribute('innerText')
except TimeoutException:
    price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#availability span').get_attribute('innerText').strip()
print(f'price: {price}')
```

Comment: I tried it for one day, chatGPT also can't give me solution and you solved it with few moments. @daniel-sabrel You are just boss. I want to be your student. I will do your your task free if you guide me. Love –